# VBA to open Word document and refresh links

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, linked-tables

I am hoping to find a solution (be it VBA or not) to my problem. I have a Word document with linked Excel tables in it. All links work correctly, but I have to manually open the Word document in order for it to refresh with the Excel data. The reason I am using Word instead of Excel is due to the large amounts of text.

Is there a way that I could program some sort of code that would go through all Word documents in a folder, open each document, refresh all links, save document, and move onto the next one?

Here's what I have so far

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String

MyFolder = "LOCATION"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.docx")

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Documents.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Ok I was able to make the open files command work! Now I am attempting to make it overwrite/save the file and close it.

*Error Message: Object Required*

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim objWord As Object

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
MyFolder = "LOCATION"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.docx")
Do While MyFile <> ""
objWord.Documents.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=MyFile
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes there is a way.  Why don't you give it a shot a post what you've tried.  We'll help with any errors, but we won't do it from scratch.

Comment: Thank you, @jbarker2160. I have posted it above.

Comment: you need to tell us what exact error you are receiving and on which line.

Comment: @jbarker2160, I am being told I need to create an object. I also don't think I have the "save" code correct.

Comment: Are you doing this in Word?

Comment: I'm doing it in Excel VBA, but yes it is for Word

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of below:

```
Dim objDoc As Object
Do While Myfile <> ""
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile)
    objDoc.Save '~~> Save
    objDoc.Close '~~> Close
    Myfile = Dir
Loop
```

Or you can just use *Close Method* like this.

```
objDoc.Close True '~~> close with SaveChanges argument set to True
```